# fast interpolate image on meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I am looking for a fast way to interpolate a 3 channel image on a grid of x-y points. I have a functioning code using `map_coordinates`. As you can see, i am doing 3 times the same thing, I would like a faster way that can do at least the 3 channels at the same time.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates

test_img = np.random.random((128, 160, 3))
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(128), np.arange(160))

# here f is a 2d -> 2d map that will return floats. In my case
# it is a function to un-fisheye a picture.
x, y = f(x,y)

def interp_img(img, x, y, order=1):
    "interpolates img on (x,y) grid"
    return np.stack([map_coordinates(img[:,:,i], np.stack([y, x]), order=order) for i in range(3)], axis=-1)

interp_img(test_img, x, y)
```

replacing the `map_coordinates` with a int casting (to find pixels) it is quite faster.

```
def int_map(img, x, y):
    "int round reindexing of image"
    return img[y.astype(int), x.astype(int), :]

%time out_img = interp_img(aimg, xc, yc)
>> CPU times: user 398 ms, sys: 72.4 ms, total: 470 ms
   Wall time: 472 ms

%time out_img_int = int_map(aimg, xc, yc)
>> CPU times: user 54.8 ms, sys: 43.9 ms, total: 98.7 ms
   Wall time: 98.5 ms
```

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question, but isn't the meshgrid is exactly the same with your image size already?

Comment: you are right, it is not exactly this, i will update the question. the vectors x, y contain a mapping of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work. (I've changed x/y to row/col to avoid confusion over swapping of axis order...)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates

test_img = np.random.random((128, 160, 3))
row, col, ch = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(128), np.arange(160), np.arange(3),
    indexing='ij',
)

# here f is a 2d -> 2d map that will return floats. In my case
# it is a function to un-fisheye a picture.
row_in, col_in = f(row, col)

def interp_img(img, r, c, ch, order=1):
    "interpolates color (3-channel) img on grid"
    return map_coordinates(img, np.stack([r, c, ch]), order=order)

interp_img(test_img, row_in, col_in, ch)
```

Comment: It is actually slower on my tests.

Comment: Dang! LOL How different is it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions, the closure worked but only for this specific test run.

Comment: I wanted to edit my question, but instead edit your answer, but could not undo it! so had to make a small edit of at least 6 chars. sorry.

Comment: No worries. If you do "order=0" it's a fairer fight, btw. ;)